# Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined at onchange

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to show the "expandrepeat" div when choosing a specific select option.
This is my not working code:

```
<script>
window.check=function(elem) {
    if (elem.selectedIndex == 1) {
        document.getElementById("expandrepeat").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("expandrepeat").style.display = 'none';
    }
};
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="information-lane">
<p class="information-title">{{trans.modal.repeat}}</p>
<select class="information-input form-control" onChange="check(this);">
    <option value="-">No repeat</option>
    <option value="-">Daily</option>
    <option value="-">Weekly</option>
    <option value="-">Monthly</option>
    <option value="-">Yearly</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––</option>
    <option value="-">Custom...</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="expandrepeat" style="display:none;">
  <p>Repeat every</p>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello T.v.A, welcome to both worlds of javascript and stackoverflow :)
You have many ways to play around this code to debug where the issue is, for example you can log at the beginning of the check function what is the selected index, also you can use selected value instead of the selected index (after you supply unique option values for sure)
Two aside questions could be, are you sure that you don't have javascript errors in the console, and the other question/advice is there a reason that you don't use jquery selectors? You will find them handful
Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to Vue, you should read the documentation on how to handle [Event Handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers).

You could also use [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) instead of setting the display property manually.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    check: function(ev) {
      if (ev.target.value === "custom")
        document.getElementById("expandrepeat").style.display = 'block';
      else
        document.getElementById("expandrepeat").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="information-lane">
  <select class="information-input form-control" @change="check">
    <option value="-">No repeat</option>
    <option value="">Daily</option>
    <option value="-">Weekly</option>
    <option value="-">Monthly</option>
    <option value="-">Yearly</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––</option>
    <option value="custom">Custom...</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="expandrepeat" style="display:none;">
  <p>Repeat every</p>
  <input>
</div>
```